# An If function that filters and then computes the Average

Tags: excel

I am trying to write a function in Excel that says takes the average of a group of numbers if they are from AUM and have a certain name. I thought maybe I could do something like:
    `=AVERAGE(IF(('FY15'!$D$1:$D$652="AUM")*('FY15'!$B$1:$B$652=$A6),'FY15'!$W$1:$W$652))`

But it does not return anything. I even tried to do it using `SUM`, how I have seen it, but still nothing. Any tips?

Comment: try the averageif function http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/averageif.php

Comment: it doesn't say anything about multiple arguments. Good idea though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Scott mentions in the comment to your question, this is probably easiest solved by using [`AVERAGEIF`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/AVERAGEIF-function-faec8e2e-0dec-4308-af69-f5576d8ac642?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB), or rather [`AVERAGEIFS`](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/AVERAGEIFS-function-48910c45-1fc0-4389-a028-f7c5c3001690) since you have several criteria. I think the formula you'd want would be:

```
=AVERAGEIFS('FY15'!$W$1:$W$652,'FY15'!$D$1:$D$652,"AUM",'FY15'!$B$1:$B$652,$A6)
```

- The first argument to the function is the range you want the average of.
- Then the following argument is the first range which has a criteria
- The third argument is the criteria you want to apply to the range specified in the second criteria.
- Arguments 4 & 5 do the same as argument 2 & 3, but for a new criteria-range.
- If you want even more criteria, add them in the same manner.

Comment: I think the parenthesis might be off.

Comment: Whoops, fixed @JackArmstrong

Comment: Thank you. Only now it says Division by 0. That is one step closer.

Comment: Hmm, is it possible there are no valid matches? Not entirely sure if the second pair of criteria is valid either, if you want the row-reference of $A6 to increase by one for each comparison. @JackArmstrong

Comment: Yea. After this I then realized I don't want the average of all them but I have to take the sum of a group and then average those sums. But this was still good to know.